# Run responsive tests in ember-cli

Tags: responsive-design, automated-tests, integration-testing, ui-testing

Is there a way to run tests based on responsive media queries and breakpoints?

For instance I am getting ready to start developing an app in ember that will be designed for the phone, so we will have some media queries in place to tell the user to open the app on their phone to continue using it.

I want to put a test in place for this as I feel it's worth doing since it depends on the rest of the app even being used how it's intended.

I'm new to testing but I understand the concepts pretty well, maybe I'm wrong and this isn't worth testing?

Can anyone point me in a direction here?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use something like [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/list-of-browsers-and-platforms?product=live) or [Sauce Labs](https://saucelabs.com/platforms/) to test for this and you may have to manually test it. Both of those services allow you to run through your website in different browsers including mobile and desktop browsers.

I don't think this kind of test can be automated.